# Reading variable in sed from forloop

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to read file and changing the variable in file using sed, but sed doesnt read the value of variable.

Here I want to replace `@@` by `market` and putting the output in another file

```
markets=au,uk,ca

IFS="," read -ra items <<<"$markets"

for item in "${items[@]}"
do
    echo "country is :: $item"
    sed -i 's/@@/${!item}/g' sample_guid >> /test/eric/Guid_del
done
```

Comment: What is that `@@` you keep using?

Comment: would be useful to see a before/after input example... using `-i` means there won't be any stdout... for variable substitution, need to [use double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/3519/substitution-using-shell-variables#t=201702201333106274056)

Comment: When you have a template file sample_guid with an `@@` to be replaced by the markets for different runs, try to remove the `-i` option of sed.

Answer (score 0):

When sample_guid looks like
This is an example for market @@. I want the market filled in here.
If you want to do this for different markets,
use the feature of printf the loop through extra parameters:

```
printf "This is an example for market %s. I want the market filled in here.\n" au uk ca
```

When sample_guid really jas only one `@@`, you can expand the `printf` solution to

```
printf "$(sed 's/@@/%s/' sample_guid)\n" $(tr "," " " <<< "${markets}")
```